# Yeoman generator for creating Ionic mobile app using Angular2 and Cordova with typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, yeoman-generator

I need to create a mobile app, can anyone help me to find yeoman generator for creating Ionic hybrid mobile applications using Angular2 Cordova with typescript.

Comment: Check this [yeoman generator](https://github.com/dsebastien/modernWebDevGenerator). I don't know if it fulfills all of your requirements, but it worth to check it out.